# Draw rectangle from function Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got a project where I want to divide up the world map into a regular grid then highlight certain parts of this grid

I've managed to successfully hack an example to draw a 20x20 rectangle on the google world map

```
 function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: {lat: 60.18, lng: 24.93},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35,
map: map,
bounds: {

  west: 180, north:0, east: -160, south: 20
}
});    

initMap();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zea831p/4/

But I'd like to turn this into a function so many rectangles can be highlighted depending on other parts of my script. I'm not having much success turning it into a function though. This is my start

```
function drawRec(w, n, e, s){


var coords = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(w, n),
        new google.maps.LatLng(e, s))

var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
   strokeColor: '   #ff00ff',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 1,
   fillColor: ' #ff00ff',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,

   bounds: coords,

   map: map

  });



}
```

I get an error of "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map" in the console.

Answer (score 0):

declare the 'map' var outside the 'initMap()' function to make it global across your script tag

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    ...
    ...
}

function drawRec(w, n, e, s){
    ...
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the function? I feel like the bounds aren't being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After that silly fix over the global variable, I got there in the end:

The west, north etc...can just set from the arguments

```
var map

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 1,
center: {lat: 60.18, lng: 24.93},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
}

function drawRec(w, n, e, s){




var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
   strokeColor: '   #ff00ff',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 1,
   fillColor: ' #ff00ff',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,

   bounds: {

  west: w, north:n, east: e, south:s
    },

   map: map

   });

}


initMap();
drawRec(180, 10, 160, 30);
```